# Sorting Neighborhoods by Population Using Heap

Tags: c#, sorting, data-structures, heap

I am trying to sort the neighborhoods by their populations. I used heap sorting algorithm in C#. I created an Array which keeps the population of the neighborhoods named "arr". And created an array which keeps the name of the hoods . It works good but how can I get output of sorting with name of the neighborhoods?

```
My code is here:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace HoodSorting
{
    public class example
    {
        static void heapSort(int[] arr, int n)
        {
            for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                heapify(arr, n, i);
            for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                int temp = arr[0];
                arr[0] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
                heapify(arr, i, 0);
            }
        }
        static void heapify(int[] arr, int n, int i)
        {
            int largest = i;
            int left = 2 * i + 1;
            int right = 2 * i + 2;
            if (left < n && arr[left] > arr[largest])
                largest = left;
            if (right < n && arr[right] > arr[largest])
                largest = right;
            if (largest != i)
            {
                int swap = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[largest];
                arr[largest] = swap;
                heapify(arr, n, largest);
            }
        }
        public static void Main()
        {// arr REPRESENTS THE POUPLATION OF THE NEIGHBORHOODS
            string[] neighborhoods = { "Bornova" ,"Westriver","Paradise","Goodman","McMountain","Rocker","Summerlin","Northcity","Greenhill","Sevenwaves"};
            int[] arr = { 55, 25, 89, 34, 12, 19, 78, 95, 1, 100 };
            int n = 10, i;
            Console.WriteLine("Heap Sort");
            Console.Write("Initial array is: ");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
            }
            heapSort(arr, 10);
            Console.Write("\nSorted Array is: ");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get output like this:

```
Sorted Array is: Greenhill, McMountain,....,........, Northcity, Sevenwaves
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an OOP perspective you would keep the two properties (name and population of a neighborhood) together in one object. Then when you sort the *objects*, you'll still have the associated data right there.

There are several ways to do this. For instance, you could create tuples.

Here is how that is applied to your code:

```
    static void heapSort(Tuple<int, string>[] arr)
    {
        int n = arr.Length;
        for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            heapify(arr, n, i);
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            (arr[0], arr[i]) = (arr[i], arr[0]);
            heapify(arr, i, 0);
        }
    }

    static void heapify(Tuple<int, string>[] arr, int n, int i)
    {
        int largest = i;
        int left = 2 * i + 1;
        int right = 2 * i + 2;
        if (left < n && arr[left].Item1 > arr[largest].Item1)
            largest = left;
        if (right < n && arr[right].Item1 > arr[largest].Item1)
            largest = right;
        if (largest != i)
        {
            (arr[i], arr[largest]) = (arr[largest], arr[i]);
            heapify(arr, n, largest);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Tuple<int, string>[] arr = {
            Tuple.Create(55, "Bornova"),
            Tuple.Create(25, "Westriver"),
            Tuple.Create(89, "Paradise"),
            Tuple.Create(34, "Goodman"),
            Tuple.Create(12, "McMountain"),
            Tuple.Create(19, "Rocker"),
            Tuple.Create(78, "Summerlin"),
            Tuple.Create(95, "Northcity"),
            Tuple.Create(1,  "Greenhill"),
            Tuple.Create(100, "Sevenwaves")
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Initial array is: ");
        foreach (var pair in arr)
        {
            Console.Write(pair.Item2 + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        heapSort(arr);

        Console.WriteLine("Sorted Array is: ");
        foreach (var pair in arr)
        {
            Console.Write(pair.Item2 + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: I would also refactor your code a bit, left and right sortings could be taken out of the heapify method, and  made more readable, plus the names "i" and "n" are really not that great names, there must be something better. nor is "largest", I mean inside method  yes, the context is clear, but still, when you come back in 6 months, will it still be easy to read? Not likely.

Remeber: Code is for humans, computers only  understand 1/0

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I am a second year computer science student and I will definitely consider your suggestion to improve the quality of my code. I have two questions about the code and career: How can I print the top 3 population neighborhood? Secondly, I want to build my IT career on business analyst or product management. I love to code, but I'm not in love enough to pursue a career. My communication skills are high and I like interacting with people. What would you suggest me to do in advance so that I can advance in the two areas I mentioned?

Comment: For the first question: after the items have been sorted, you can access the first three at the start of the array. If you are *only* interested to get the top three and not the sorted list, then you shouldn't need HeapSort. You should just create the heap and pop the first three elements from the heap.

Comment: Thanks I have just done it.